# MySQL Query for aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I am stuck with a query for aggregation on a data set. My Data set is as :

[image]

Rel Scope is the scope of the release which is as Actual / Planned.
I want the aggregate to be populated in "CatStat Scope" column which is the Scope of the category for a particular release.

Which might be like SUM(Actual) / SUM(Planned) where Category = 'xxx' and RelStat = 'yyy' where 'xxx' is the category on the same row and 'yyy' is the relstat on the same row.

I would expect a result like :
[image]

The highlighted cells have the same figures as they belong to the same Category and RelStat.

Comment: Not sure why you would store derived data, but this just requires a simple subquery.

Comment: I have to use this to populate a chart on excel and would need all the calculations to flow into the query. As I am using a data model in my Excel Pivot which do not allow me calculated fields. Please could you help me with the sub query ?

Comment: Update mytable a join (select x, y, sum(z) q from my table group by x,y) b on b.x = a.x and b.y = a.y set a.q = b.q

Comment: Build a sql schema with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and give a lonk address here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the scope per `(RelStat, Category)` group in a subquery.  Join back to the main table to be able to show individual rows:

```
select  yt.*
,       scope.CatStatScope
from    YourTabe yt
join    (
        select  RelStat
        ,       Category
        ,       sum(Actual) / sum(Planned) as CatStatScope
        from    YourTable
        group by
                RelStat
        ,       Category
        ) as scope
on      scope.RelStat = yt.RelStat
        and scope.Category = yt.Category
```